# Magento Image Url "_1.png" added to Image URL

Tags: magento

On my website Magento adds _1 to the end of some Image urls.

So my normal basic urls should be ...media/catalog/product/cache/9/A/E/test-small.png

but somehow for some images it alters to ...media/catalog/product/cache/9/A/E/test3-small_1.png

My normal image names are unique numbers so I´m confused why this happens?
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento will add a `_1` after any image if the file already exists on the server.
Please mind that Magento is not doing cleaning of the images of products when / if you delete one product.

Comment: would it be possible to delete these somehow when you delete a product? Or is there a script with which i can solve this issue quickly?

Comment: I deleted all images and then did a bulk upload of the images again to get the proper image links. So I guess that works best and is the easiest

Answer (score 0):

It is magento's by default feature, if the image name you are trying to upload already exist it will rename your current image name with _Number. Check before uploading.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this post using M2 and is having the same issue.  Check out the media/tmp folder.  I was working on an api image sync and the name kept having a _1, _2 etc after the image.

It turns out Magento doesn't always give a clear reason if something fails in the api so the file was making it to the tmp directory but never the final destination causing the file name issue.